# Plugin to create forms using HTML

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, forms

Until recently I've been using Custom Contact Forms to create some more advanced forms. The sole reason I've chosen this plugin was the ability to create my own layouts and basically just code clean HTML with CCF taking care of the rest.

However, recently I came across [this topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-custom-contact-forms-spam-can-be-sent-through-ccf) and realized how vulnerable the plugin might actually be. Therefore, my question is: is there any other safe Forms plugin that allows me to create my own HTML-based - not UI-based - forms? I'd be grateful for any suggestions.

Edit: Since I don't want to expose the vulnerability (however obvious it is), a temporary solution is to hard-code the recipient e-mail in the plugin code itself. If anybody would like to do that find and edit: `/wp-contents/plugins/custom-contact-forms/custom-contact-forms-front.php line 427` and replace

```
$dest_email_array = $this->getDestinationEmailArray($_POST['destination_email']);
```

with

```
$dest_email_array = $this->getDestinationEmailArray('your@mail.com');
```

Other solutions I can think of, if you really are stuck with the plugin and have to use different e-mail recipients, is to use [Advanced Custom Fields Plugin](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/), to create page-dependent recipients, however, it's not a place to describe the quite lengthy process of doing so.

Comment: Sorry, plugin/theme recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) here. Try the [WordPress group on Google+](https://plus.google.com/communities/101504763068635549461) or [wordpress.org forums](http://wordpress.org/support/).

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [ContactForm7](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/screenshots/) it is a nice combination of easy to use and customizable at the same time. You can input html directly into the form if you'd like, and it doesn't suffer from the same vulnerabilities that CCF does.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The plugin you mentioned also seems to have a worrisome number of 1-star ratings. You didn't encounter any problems with it?

Comment: I've used it in the past on many projects without any issues. It is free so you have nothing to lose if you want to try it out. The majority of those one star ratings seem to be from people who couldn't figure out how to use it, entered their email address wrong, or don't have their mail server configured properly.